# Partial specialization of non-type parameter

Tags: c++

I understand how  specialization works for type/pointer to type:

```
template <typename T> class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass() { std::cout << "TestClass: general" << std::endl; }
};

template <typename T> class TestClass<T*>
{
public:
    TestClass() { std::cout << "TestClass: pointer" << std::endl; }
};

TestClass<int> tc1; //TestClass: general
TestClass<int*> tc2; // TestClass: pointer
```

but if we have

```
template<auto N> class S
{
public:
    S() { std::cout << "auto template" << std::endl; }
};

template<char N> class S<N>
{
public:
    S() { std::cout << "char template" << std::endl; }
};
```

If I use it like:

```
S<20U> s1; //char template
S<'c'> s2; //char template
```

in both case I get char template;

What is the meaning of writing

```
template<char N> class S<N>
```

and when the 'auto' template will be called then?

Comment: `S<20U> s1;` will use the primary template(with auto). Your first comment is wrong.

Comment: @JasonLiam VS2022 uses char template

Comment: Seems like a **msvc and clang bug**. Both uses the `char` specialization for `S<20U> s1;` while gcc uses the primary template `auto`.

Comment: You could be adding a function for creating the objects and add a type parameter and a value parameter: `template<auto N>
auto MakeS()
{
    return S<decltype(N), N>{};
}` `auto s1 = MakeS<20u>();` : https://godbolt.org/z/r4KEWofWz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the 'auto' template will be called then?

The **primary template** `template<auto N> class S` will be used whenever the non-type parameter `N` is of type other than `char`. This means that it will be used for

```
S<20U> s1; //auto template
```

[GCC Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/4veeTP1vW)

Output:

```
auto template
char template
```

---

Here is the clang bug:

[Clang chooses specialization over primary template for non-type template parameter](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/58449)

Here is the msvc bug:

[MSVC chooses specialization over primary template for non-type template parameter](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-chooses-specialization-over-primary/10175880)

Comment: Can you back this up with some quotes or something?  Two of the three main compilers disagree with you

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm also submitting the bug reports for those compilers(clang and msvc) as i'm pretty sure the primary template should be used. WIll probably add quotes after submitting bugs.